# Why is the console returning "TypeError: newIndustry is null"?

Tags: javascript

Does any one see what goes wrong when I get to this line...

```
    newIndustry.innerHTML = industryNews[generateRandomNumber()-1]
}
```

Here is my source js(I'm just dropping text in to a h1 with `#industryNews`)

```
var industryNews = [];
industryNews[0] = "Lorem ipsum dolor <strong>sit</strong> amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio, ut, maxime, eum, fugit dolor nulla cupiditate beatae sapiente dignissimos accusamus cumque fuga alias accusantium praesentium nisi placeat quam ad eius.";
industryNews[1] = "Lorem ipsum dolor <strong>sit</strong> amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident, consequuntur, officia veritatis molestias odio nobis minima iste id tenetur possimus magni nisi error enim minus aperiam? Minus, iure delectus cumque.";
industryNews[2] = "Lorem ipsum dolor <strong>sit</strong> amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint, in, qui voluptatibus voluptas inventore recusandae non quos adipisci dolor beatae dolore saepe quaerat exercitationem dolores delectus quo pariatur. Quae, quidem.";
industryNews[3] = "Lorem ipsum dolor <strong>sit</strong> amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda, sed, laborum, quisquam rerum quo non aspernatur necessitatibus soluta id debitis impedit corporis magnam praesentium ab odit dicta aperiam autem consequuntur!";

var newIndustry = document.getElementById("industryNews");

// generate a # between 1 &4
function generateRandomNumber(){
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(4)+1);
}

function updateindustryNews () {
    // var interval = generateRandomNumber();
    newIndustry.innerHTML = industryNews[generateRandomNumber()-1]
}

updateindustryNews();

setInterval(updateindustryNews,4000);
```

Comment: Do you have an element with `id="industryNews"` at the time your script is executing?

Comment: http://ctec.clark.edu/~h.nelson5/ctec126/project/final/

Comment: Why are you posting a link? How about answering @Amadan's question?

Comment: Yes, please just find out. Also, [array literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Array_literals) are your friend.

Comment: 99% sure you are trying to reference it before it is rendered on the page.

Comment: make sure the `var newIndustry = document.getElementById("industryNews");` is executed once `industryNews` is loaded in the dom... the best way to do it is to use a document ready handler

Comment: Also, note that `generateRandomNumber` should be returning `Math.floor(Math.random()*industryNews.length)`, which will return a number from 0 to 3, which is inside the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot `document.getElementById()` on a page before HTML exists. So, your script tag has to be at the bottom of your body or in your head. If in your head, you must use `onload` which is a property of `window`, which is implicit.

Also, nothing to do with your problem, but `Math.random()` returns a number between 0 and .9 repeating, never 1, so

```
function generateRandomNumber(){
  return Math.floor(Math.random()*(4)+1);
}
```

is a lame formula, since `Math.floor(0.99999*4+1)` = 4. Should be:

```
function generateRandomNumber(){
  return Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
}
```

Now you don't have to -1.

Comment: I tossed the function in an on load, that was it! Thanks very much! Silly of me honestly; I should have known better. Lesson learned.

Comment: Im glad you showed me how to improve my generateRandomNumber function. Many thanks!